# Heroku error when attempting to deploy app from dropbox

Tags: express, heroku, content-type

I am trying to deploy a node app on heroku via the web GUI for dropbox, and I get the error:

```
Item could not be modified:

    "Content-Type" request header must be set to "application/json".
```

Any clues as to what that might mean?

Disclaimer: I was not the one who wrote the app, just made two mods for heroku.

Answer (score 1):

In case you haven't found an answer... I have the same problem.
You probably need to update your runtime stack.

Here's Heroku's message on their website:
"The legacy Cedar-10 stack has been deprecated and reached its end-of-life on November 4, 2015. Applications may continue running, however you will not be able to push to your application without upgrading to Cedar-14 first."

How to update informations are available here: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar-14-migration#upgrading-the-production-app-to-cedar-14

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I raised a ticket at Heroku. They replied,

> *"Are you using Firefox? We seen this recently with Firefox and we are currently working on a fix. In the meantime, you can use another browser like Google Chrome for deploying your app."*

And using Google Chrome fixes the problem.